# warning about pdfpages with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages

Package `pageslts` prints out this warning since I use `pdfpages` and `hyperref` in the same document.

> Package pageslts Warning: Package pdfpages detected.
>   (pageslts)                Using hyperref with pdfpages can cause problems. See
>   (pageslts)                ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/
>   (pageslts)                macros/latex/contrib/pax/
>   (pageslts)                for project pax (PDFAnnotExtractor)..

What does this mean?
Am I supposed to change anything in the document or when am I going to see any problem?

Comment: I think that it's nothing to be worried about; hyperlinks in the PDF included with `pdfpages` will be lost, but this is known. The PAX program by H. Oberdiek can be used to reinstate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know why `pageslts` issues this warning, as the problem doesn't seem to concern it.

It's a fact that PDF included partially or totally via `pdfpages`'s `\includepdf` but also with the standard `\includegraphics` command lose their hyperlinks, but this has nothing to do with having loaded `hyperref` (of course, without it there will be *no* link whatsoever).

A partial solution to the "lost links" is provided by Heiko Oberdiek's project PAX (PDFAnnotExtractor) with the script `pdfannotextractor` and related programs.